# SWIG Coolprop wrapping for Golang

Tags: c++, go, swig, cgo

I would like to be able to use [CoolProp](http://www.coolprop.org/) c++ library inside my Go code. Unfortunately, there is currently no wrapper for Go ([CoolProp Wrappers](http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/index.html)) so I'm trying to generate it by myself using SWIG.

First I get the source file from `coolpop` repository. The main header file is `coolprop/include/CoolProp.h`

```
git clone git@github.com:CoolProp/CoolProp.git coolprop
```

Basically the header file look like :

```
#ifndef CoolProp_H
#define CoolProp_H

    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "DataStructures.h"

    namespace CoolProp {

    double Props1SI(std::string FluidName, std::string Output);

    /* many others functions in the real file */

    } /* namespace CoolProp */
#endif
```

Below is the interface file that I write inspired by [zacg repository](https://github.com/zacg/simplelib).

**gocoolprop.i**

```
%module gocoolprop

%include <typemaps.i>
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

// This will create 2 wrapped types in Go called
// "StringVector" and "ByteVector" for their respective
// types.
namespace std {
   %template(StringVector) vector<string>;
   %template(ByteVector) vector<char>;
}

%include "coolprop/include/CoolProp.h"
```

I'm generating **gocoolprop.go** and **gocoolprop_wrap.cxx** using the following command:

```
swig -go -cgo -c++ -intgosize 64 gocoolprop.i
```

The swig command works well and the files are generated without any errors. My IDE is even able to recognize all the function when I import the go package.

However, when I try to build the package I obtain a lot of errors all similar to :

```
# gocoolprop
gocoolprop_wrap.cxx: In function 'double _wrap_Props1SI_gocoolprop_f0fd25a1f15e9efe(_gostring_, _gostring_)':
gocoolprop_wrap.cxx:632:20: error: 'CoolProp' has not been declared
   result = (double)CoolProp::Props1SI(arg1,arg2);
```

The 'CoolProp' is a namespace inside the CoolProp.h header file. I think I may have to add something inside the gocoolprop.i file for this. I take a look inside the [c++ part of the swig documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_namespaces), but I didn't find anything special about namespaces.

Any advice would be very helpful, it's my first time using swig.

I'm using Go version 1.11 windows/amd64 and SWIG Version 3.0.12 compiled with  with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ [i686-w64-mingw32].

Comment: would you mind commenting here: https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/issues/1871